# Ko-Grid throwing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, kogrid

I just loaded KO Grid in to my application to see how it turns out. While trying it kept on failing showing me error that ko is not defined. in fact, I am can see KnockOut library bein gloaded in my firebug and other code which is using Knockout is functioning without any complains.

Anyhow, We also use require js as part of our framework so I decided to ut some Require code in the Ko-grid.js.

Now it fails on "self.data" where it says neither self nor data are defined. I am pretty sure a lot of people are using ko grid out there and there is some problem in my settings but the kind of error that it is throwing is just not making any sense.

Anybody faced this kind of problem with it before?